# Docker RUN command near end of Dockerfile ... boots into container unless I give a CMD at the end but doesn't work either way. Any ideas?

Tags: docker, gcloud

I am working on a Dockerfile to be used with Google Cloud Run.

I'm not getting the command to run.

Here's the (slightly obfuscated) Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli:latest

RUN apt-get update

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt /root/

RUN pip install -r /root/requirements.txt

RUN useradd -m ubuntu

ENV HOME=/home/ubuntu
USER ubuntu
COPY --chown=ubuntu:ubuntu . /home/ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

RUN gcloud config set project our-customer-tech-sem-prod

RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=./service/our-customer-tech-sem-prod-a02b2c7f4536.json

RUN gcloud compute config-ssh

ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./service/our-customer-tech-sem-prod-a02b2c7f4536.json

CMD ["gcloud", "compute", "ssh", "--internal-ip", "our-persist-cluster-py3-prod", "--zone=us-central1-b", "--project", "our-customer-tech-sem-prod", "--", "'ps -ef'", "|",  "./checker2.py"]
```

This tries to run the CMD at the end, but says it can't find the host specified. (Runs fine from the command line outside Docker.)

Comment: You may want to post your docker file for people to be able to help you effectively.

Comment: There are a few issues. (1) You cannot deploy this as a Cloud Run service but you may be able to deploy it as a [Cloud Run job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs). Services must listen on a socket. (2) Using Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) in a container requires a very specific authentication flow (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-docker)) ; (3) Your `Dockerfile` references a Service Account that it expects, you don't and you very much should **not** put in the container

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does `checker.py` do?

Comment: checker2.py scans through the ps -ef link to find too-long running jobs and users that are running jobs their own IDs and shouldn't be'

Comment: I looked at the authentication flow and got through it and authenticated, but how then to get that authentication into my Dockerfile? I took out the other stuff and (a) it still boots into the container and (b) I still can't get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things wrong at the end (1) typo in the host name (fixed with the help of a colleague) ... then I had to make the CMD into a shell script to get the pipe inside to work correctly.

Here's the final (slightly obfuscated) script:

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli:latest

RUN apt-get update

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt /root/

RUN pip install -r /root/requirements.txt

RUN useradd -m ubuntu

RUN mkdir /secrets

COPY secrets/* /secrets

ENV HOME=/home/ubuntu
USER ubuntu
COPY --chown=ubuntu:ubuntu . /home/ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

RUN gcloud config set project our-customer-tech-sem-prod

RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=./service/our-customer-tech-sem-prod-a02b2c7f4536.json

RUN gcloud compute config-ssh

ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./service/our-customer-tech-sem-prod-a02b2c7f4536.json

CMD ["./rungcloud.sh"]
```